# One liner to get X elements from slice

Tags: rust

I have a method that takes a `&[u8]` and I need to extract elements from the beginning up to a specific index, copying them into a `String`. I could use a loop to iterate through it but is there a one-liner to do so that I'm missing?

Comment: `xs[..index]` ? It's not clear *how* you want these elements... cloned or referenced

Comment: "extract" as in into a Vec? a subslice?

Comment: I want to clone them into a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the initial sequence is `seq` and the index is `idx`, then it is `String::from_utf8(seq[..idx].to_vec()).unwrap()`. By steps:

1. `seq[..idx]` gets the desired slice `&[u8]`;
2. `seq[..idx].to_vec()` converts this slice into `Vec<u8>` (of course, the expensive cloning is going on, but it is necessary if the slice is immutable);
3. `String::from_utf8(seq[..idx].to_vec())` tries to convert `Vec<u8>` into a string in place. Since `String` shall have a valid UTF8 sequence of bits, it checks for this condition and returns a `Result`. No cloning is happening here: instead the `String` takes ownership of the `Vec` and reuses its content. The docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8
4. Finally `.unwrap()` converts the `Result` into `String` if you are sure that the UTF8 representation was correct. Alternatively, you can use `.expect("error message")` or use `match` to handle a possible encoding error.

**EDIT:**
A better method was suggested in the comments: `std::str::from_utf8(&x[..idx]).unwrap()`. This is similar, but avoids allocating new memory. You can bind this to the variable of type `&str` instead of `String` - they are interchangeable for many purposes.
If you really want a `String`, you can allocate new memory and convert by `String::from(std::str::from_utf8(&x[..idx]).unwrap())`. Compared to the method above this has an advantage that memory allocation is avoided when the slice is not valid UTF8.

Comment: you can use `std::str::from_utf8` instead, it takes a byte slice so there's no allocation for vector. Then just convert the string slice to a string.

Comment: Then the allocation happens when you convert `&str` to a `String`. A `String` is an owning collection, so it cannot reuse something that belongs to other collection; otherwise it would be impossible for the borrow checker to enforce that nobody has a mutable reference to the `String` contents.
However, you are correct that `std::str::from_utf8` is a good idea too if you actually don't mutate the slice. In this case you probably don't need to create a `String` at all.

Comment: under the hood they should be the same because `String::from_utf8` calls `std::str::from_utf8`, but in the case when the byte slice is not valid, `std::str::from_utf8` has one fewer allocation

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said how you want them formatted in the string. Here is one attempt, assuming you want each `u8` converted to it's decimal representation and separated by commas:

```
fn foo(s: &[u8], index: usize) -> String {
    s[..index].iter().map(u8::to_string).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(",")
}
```

Note that `join` in the std library operates on slices rather than iterators, which is why you have to collect them into a `Vec` first.

Or if your `[u8]` contained a sequence of utf8 encoded characters, you might want this:

```
fn bar(s: &[u8], index: usize) -> String {
    String::from_utf8(s[..index].to_vec()).unwrap()
}
```

In this case you probably want to return a `Result` instead of unwrapping as I have done in this example.